# Can't access JSON from array

Tags: json

Am trying to build a stock price widget using JSON from https://www.worldtradingdata.com

It works in that I can access values, but not from within an array. IE. from this demo:

`{"message":"This request is for demonstration purposes only. If you wish to use our API, please sign up and get your personal API token for free.","symbols_requested":3,"symbols_returned":3,"data":[{"symbol":"AAPL","name":"Apple Inc.","currency":"USD","price":"222.77" ...`

I can access "message", but not "price" which is the value that I want to display. I have tried three different ways to achieve this, see [https://codepen.io/LF12/pen/oNvaQjL][1], but obviously there's some other issue that I'm unaware of. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>

<body>

    <h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>
    <p>This content is imported from the JSON file at <a
            href="https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo"
            target="_blank">https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo</a></p>

    This is the value from the name "message":
    <p style="color: red" id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.message;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>

    <hr>

    <h2>Get value from inside array, take 1</h2>


    <p>This content is imported from the JSON file at <a
            href="https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo"
            target="_blank">https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo</a> but
        is inside an array. It returns 'undefined' instead of the value, "222.77".</p>

    <p style="color: red" id="demo-2"></p>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo-2").innerHTML = myObj.data.price;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>

    <hr>

    <h2>Take 2</h2>

    <p>This content is imported from the JSON file at <a
            href="https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo"
            target="_blank">https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo</a> but
        is inside an array. It returns 'undefined' instead of the value, "222.77".</p>

    <p style="color: red" id="demo-3"></p>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo-3").innerHTML = myObj.data["price"];
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>

    <hr>

    <h2>Take 3</h2>

    <p>This content is imported from the JSON file at <a
            href="https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo"
            target="_blank">https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo</a> but
        is inside an array. It returns 'undefined' instead of the value, "222.77".</p>

    <p style="color: red" id="demo-4"></p>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("demo-4").innerHTML = myArr[3];
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AAPL,MSFT,HSBA.L&api_token=demo", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>



</body>

</html>


  [1]: https://codepen.io/LF12/pen/oNvaQjL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` property of `myObj` is an array of objects, so to access the `price` property of any of its elements you must use an index like

```
myObj.data[0].price
```

This would give you the price for the first element of the `data` array.